# How can I find the number of current subscriptions using PrivatePub and Faye in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, messaging, faye, private-pub

I am using a ruby gem called [PrivatePub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) and this uses [Faye](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails) to offer PubSub messaging

The PrivatePub gem offers a couple of view based helpers to subscribe / send a message to a particular topic. I am looking to extend PrivatePub to include an API call which will give me the ID of each of the current subscription objects connected to Faye. Can somebody explain how this can be achieved or help me find another way to work out all the current subscriptions from the PrivatePub api.

Comment: That gem hasn't been maintained in 3 years. You may want to look at more up-to-date solutions. The gem was written for rails 3, we're about to get rails 5.

Comment: It works and solves the problem I needed it to. It still works at Rails 4 so I don't see the need in completely changing Gems, this is just a small extension to what is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 0.7, Faye includes an API for monitoring activity going on within the engine. This means you can attach event listeners to monitor the creation and destruction of client sessions, find out when clients subscribe and unsubscribe from channels, and watch published messages.

You attach an event listener to your server like so:

```
var bayeux = new Faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 45})

bayeux.on('handshake', function(clientId) {
  // event listener logic
})
```

The available events are:

- **handshake [clientId]** – Triggered when a new client connects and is issued with an ID.
- **subscribe [clientId, channel]** – Triggered when a client subscribes to a channel. This does not fire if a /meta/subscribe message is received for a subscription that already exists.
- **unsubscribe [clientId, channel]** – Triggered when a client unsubscribes from a channel. This can fire either because the client explicitly sent a /meta/unsubscribe message, or because its session was timed out by the server.
- **publish [clientId, channel, data]** – Triggered when a non-/meta/** message is published. Includes the client ID of the publisher (which may be null), the channel the message was sent to and the data payload.
- **disconnect [clientId]** – Triggered when a client session ends, either because it explicitly sent a /meta/disconnect message or because its session was timed out by the server.

I hope that this helps

Comment: So which application do I put this Code? Is it to go into the application which runs Faye, or should it go in the application with the PrivatePub client gem?